# Use parent prop on child component prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code :

```
import React from "react"
import sectionStyles from "./section.module.css"
import Title from "../title/title"

export default ({ children }) => (
  <div className={sectionStyles.container}>
    <Title titleText={props.sectionText}></Title>
    {children}
  </div>
)
```

So in the page I can do :

```js
<Section sectionText="Skills"></Section>;
```

The `sectionText="Skills"` will go pass down to the title component prop and render the text from the parent prop.

I want to be able to use title as a standalone component and inside section parent component.

I am getting :

> error  'props' is not defined  no-undef

Any ideas if this is possible?

Comment: Post your `<Title />` component code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use props in `Section` component `{ children, ...props }`:

```js
import React from "react";
import sectionStyles from "./section.module.css";
import Title from "../title/title";

// I think its the best approach,
// destruct the necessary props and style with the rest.
// now you can style title from its parent
export default ({ children, sectionText, ...props }) => (
  <div className={sectionStyles.container}>
    <Title {...props} titleText={sectionText}></Title>
    {children}
  </div>
)

// When there are too many props used inside the component
export default props => {
  const { children, sectionText, ..., ... ,... } = props;
  return (
    <div className={sectionStyles.container}>
      <Title titleText={sectionText}></Title>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};

// Tomato tomato
export default ({ children, ...props }) => (
  <div className={sectionStyles.container}>
    <Title titleText={props.sectionText}></Title>
    {children}
  </div>
);

export default ({ children, sectionText }) => (
  <div className={sectionStyles.container}>
    <Title titleText={sectionText}></Title>
    {children}
  </div>
)

export default props => (
  <div className={sectionStyles.container}>
    <Title titleText={props.sectionText}></Title>
    {props.children}
  </div>
);
```

In case you don't destruct props:

```js
export default ({ children, props }) => (...);
```

The [`ReactElement`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement) will consider `props` as a property:

`<MyComponent props={42}/>`

Also, take note that `props` isn't a reserved keyword or something:

```js
export default ({ children, ...rest }) => (
  <div className={sectionStyles.container}>
    <Title titleText={rest.sectionText}></Title>
    {children}
  </div>
)
```

Comment: I was so close because I tried just adding props. why is the ... necessary in this case?

Comment: It's [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), you can use props in various ways (its just js), I'll edit the answer and try to show the most used ones

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate it, i'll give you the nod for that info

Comment: is it possible to explain why ...props work but not props?

Comment: Yes, I'll add it now

Comment: thank you! you went above and beyond for me and for that i'm very thankful